# How to output a JavaScript array to HTML links?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have read a lot of answers telling me how to turn an arrray into a string, or put each item into an unordered list, but I was wondering if there is an easy way to output each item in the array as its own link? For a school project so please no jQuery, JavaScript only.

Comment: Yes,  you can create a bunch of A elements dynamically.

Comment: My code is too long to post, but I haven't tried much. I'm very new to this. My array is named finalOptions and is currently being printed to the console, but I want to turn it into a list of links, basically.

Comment: @PM77-1 can you explain? I'm sorry I am very new to this

Comment: It's not much different than outputting a list,  instead of LI elements you need to create A (anchor)  elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the DOM dynamically.

something like this:

```
var arrayOfLinks = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.youtube.com'];
var placeToPutLinks = document.getElementById('the-id-of-a-dom-element');

for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfLinks.length; i++) {
  var anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
  var hrefValue = arrayOfLinks[i];
  anchorTag.href = hrefValue;
  placeToPutLinks.appendChild(anchorTag);
}
```

Here are some references: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

I hope this helps,

Rhys

Comment: Thanks! I will try this. One more question- do you know if I can create these <a> tags on a new HTML page or if they will have to be part of my existing one?

Comment: Remember not to just copy and paste code my friend. Look at it.
`placeToPutLinks`. Read the references I've given to you :)

Comment: Just tried it like this and it doesn't seem to be working. No errors in the console but I'm not seeing what I'm supposed to be seeing.

   function makeLinks() {
    var placeToPutLinks = document.getElementById("results");
        for (var i=0; i < finalOptions.length; i++) {
            console.log("this is working");
            var anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
            var hrefValue = finalOptions[i];
            anchorTag.href = hrefValue;
            placeToPutLinks.appendChild(anchorTag);
        }
    };

    makeLinks();

Comment: Thats because youre missing a '}' to end your function. My code works.

Comment: You are not creating an array. I have updated the fixed code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a hint

1. Create array
2. Loop through array and write an unordered list - or anything else.

Example array:
itemList=["Canada", "US", "Mexico", "Belize", "Guatemala", "Honduras", "El Salvador", "Nicaragua", "Costa Rica", "Panama"];

Loop through the list:

```
for(var i=0; i<itemList.length; i++){

document.getElementById("myList").innerHTML+=
    '<li>' +
    itemList[i]  + 
    '</li>'
}
```

Notice that the above loop is placed in a div with an id called "myList"

It would make sense to put the loop in a function and then call the function with the array.

name the function say: writeItems
ex: function writeItems()

call the function and pass the array writeItems(itemList);

This should be a good start.

Good Luck

Comment: Make a fiddle with what I've given you. I gave you all the pieces to the puzzle. Try it and if you have problems I'll help you out.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/59fp5muy/

Here's the link but it won't work without the images

Comment: @tarlyo - you're trying with too much. Get the basic down. Get the above to work. When you have that down, then add more in. Make it so you can create an array and then write from that array.  I

Comment: Start slower. Write an array and call it. Then instead of passing a simple string (say Canada) pass a url. Then get that to display. People will help. But you will need to work your way up. This needs to become automatic.